# How to store static text on a website with django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django and I have I think a pretty fundamental question.

Lets say I have this theme:

[image]

I made a project already, so I know a bit about know how to build models for dynamic content, pass them to views and admin panel etc, but:

**Question:** on the image above I marked 3 containers that include text. There is only one instance of this text on the whole website, and it's not repeatable. If I developed for myself I would just hard-code that, but what if I develop for a client, who needs to be able to edit those fields using the admin panel?

Am I supposed to create a separate class containing multiple (lets say 20) fields for these kind of containers for the whole website, pass that class in a view (and filter with `[:1]`) to use it in a template?

Thats the only thing I came up with. Although it would work I think it's a terrible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is write a model that contains a `TextField` for the blurb to insert and a `CharField` to identify it, and a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that reads the blurb from the database by the argument you pass to it.

```
class Blurb(models.Model):
  ident = models.CharField(..., db_index=True)
  blurb = models.TextField(...)

PK  ident  text
1   main   Hey! Do you like this template? This...

{% load blurb %}
 ...
{% blurb main %}
```

Comment: Going to spend some time to try to understand how this works and ill report how it went afterwards, thanks :)

Comment: ok, i got my head around it. since documentation states: "The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc." This would imply that im going to be able to use certain template tag only in template related to certains app view right? This means i should create different "blurb" classes for every app right?

Comment: You will create one separate "blurb" app, containing a model, a template tag library, and optionally an admin view.

Comment: just made it, and its working! still trying to improve the concept, so it was more user-proof, gonna show results later! :D thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

you could have 1 model with a selection field containing a descriptor for the text in the model.

Something like:

```
class SomeText(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=POSITION_DESCRIPTORS)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Gonna read about how descriptors do work, and ill be back here, thanks!

Comment: And how should i pass it to the template? should i make SomeText class a global, that would be accessible across whole website using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS?